# WP Cli will not execute on Windows

Tags: wp-cli, windows, command-line

I have tried to install Wordpress CLI on my windows machine running windows 10.
But for some reason everytime i try to run the

```
wp
```

Command it says

```
'sh' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.
```

I have tried multiple times to reinstall it and set it up from scratch with different guides but it just won't work.

This is what the bat file says

```
@ECHO OFF
SET BIN_TARGET=%~dp0/./wp-cli.phar
php "%BIN_TARGET%" %*
```

This is the environment variable i am using to point it to the bat file
[image]

That is where the .phar file and my .bat file are located to run the CLI.

All help is appreciated

Regards

Jonas Bang

Comment: Where did the .bat come from? I'm surprised they gave you one if it then needs sh. But it looks you'll need a unix-like environment for your Windows e.g. Git bash or WSL2. Note however [the homepage says](https://wp-cli.org/) "limited support in Windows environment"

Comment: have you attempted the official windows install method at https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/guides/installing/#installing-on-windows? Note that WP CLI has limited compatibility on a Windows non-Unix environment. You would be better off with a containerised/virtual environment that provides Linux, such as WSL or perhaps even git bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently i have several process running in my CI/CD with wp-cli and all works fine in windows and unix. In my experience this is your best option in windows:

**#1** [Add PHP to your Windows Path Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736528/how-to-set-the-env-variable-for-php)

**#2** Install, as [@Rup](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/3276/rup) suggests, [Git-bash terminal](https://git-scm.com/downloads).

**#3** Execute an wp-cli command like that:

```
vendor/bin/wp cache flush --path=public/wp-cms/wp-core
```

**This code consider you are using wp-cli managed with [composer](https://packagist.org/packages/wp-cli/), and the files are locatted at vendor folder, otherwise you can replace `vendor/bin/wp` with `wp`*

[image]